# Cloudfoundry: SSL cert for shared domain

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

It's not possible to request a SSL cert for a shared Domain

[image]

The domain has been shared with `cf share-private-domain ORG DOMAIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation - it's currently not possible to request a TLS cert for a shared domain. We will make this possible soon.

Answer (score 0):

The Let's Encrypt Certificate request needs to be submitted from the organisation that is the owning organisation of the domain. In your case, this is the organisation that owns "3ap.ch".